# TypeScript a better way optional constructor parameter based on interface

Tags: typescript

Let's say I got this interface:

```
// IFoo.d.ts
export default interface IFoo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
```

and I use it here

```
// FooModel.ts
import IFoo from "./IFoo";

export default class FooModel implements IFoo {
  foo = 'hello';
  bar = 1;

  constructor(_fooModel?: IFoo) {
    if (_fooModel === undefined) return; // <-- this is what I am talking about
    this.foo = _fooModel.foo;
    this.bar = _fooModel.bar
  }
}
```

is there a better (more elegant and readable to be specific) way to reproduce this? I'm mainly talking about the `if undefined return` statement. Which will apply their default values if it returns, of course.

Comment: @T. J. Crowder thanks, fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd use a destructured parameter with a default value, like this:

```
export default class FooModel implements IFoo {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;

    constructor({foo = "hello", bar = 1} : Partial<IFoo> = {}) {
// Prop defaults −−−−^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−^^^                  ^^^^−−−−− overall default
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyM2AXMgM5hSgDmA3IcgEZxTkgCuAts9IwF98+APQAqCAA8ADpihhkAEwjxOAGzBiRyBGrgUKyLJgCymZWuTBu0tRG4RwhjNjxMiJTOSo0QDdyxsHDx8UIwBCJggPpwIYHIAFLieyAC8yABEABYQamqYGQA0gVBpyACMAsjkAApsYMBwagA8LpgAfGW4AgCUbkQDA2BZwBQAdCnpnoyDg8OjY6yl6UszA0JC+JHRCjDlZSAQAO5G2GYWCT2M2xSYdmP5tAl7E9hXyCLa2bn5GVtRt3uj2e5UWbHenwqwhek0ykgyjBeSzKABYAEzXAG7NEHY6nUzmXIgq7-aJ3CAPTBPGBo16YCFfSSkwEU4E0sFQBnIdH4IA)

In that example, the default expression isn't evaluated unless it's needed, so even an expensive expression is fine.

That also lets you assign partial `IFoo`s (just `foo` or just `bar`). If you don't want that, move the default values into the overal initializer, like this:

```
    constructor({foo, bar}: IFoo = {foo: "hello", bar: 1}) {
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyM2AXMgM5hSgDmA3IcgEZxTkgCuAts9IwF98+APQAqCAA8ADpihhkAEwjxOAGzBiRyBGrgUKyLJgCymZWuTBu0tRG4RwhjNjxMiJTOSo0QDdyxsHDx8UIwBCJggPpwIYHIAFLieADSBUALkLjgAvHie5ABEABYQamqYhWms7MgAjAIAlG5Era1gxcAUAHSeyHmejG1tHV3dNf3pQ61CQviR0QowdZMgEADuRthmFgmNjAsUmHbdFbQJy73Y+8gi2iVlFYXzUUcnZxd142w3d-XClz6eUKkkKjEuEzyABYAEwHV5LGGrDZbUzmMqffYvaLHCCnTDnGAwq6YX73STYt54j5E75QMnIWHCQ5LADMyM2xh2GNwTXot20AB4ciLkABRKBQORpbhdCh0ZAAA08iuQcBAiiVNUVQA)

---

FWIW, note that the values in the initializers on the properties in your original code will always be assigned, your constructor is currently effectively:

```
// Your current code, in effect
constructor(_fooModel?: IFoo) {
    this.foo = 'hello';
    this.bar = 1;
    if (_fooModel === undefined) return;
    this.foo = _fooModel.foo;
    this.bar = _fooModel.bar;
}
```

That's just fine, but I thought I'd mention it in case there was an expensive expression being used instead.